# Satisfying the hypotheses of the First Isomorphism Theorem.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be the group of invertible upper triangular $2 \times 2$ matrices with real entries and let $H$ be the subset of $G$ consisting of those matrices $A$ with $a_{11} = 1$.  It is easy to see that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

What is eluding me is how to construct an epimorphism for which $H$ is the kernel so that I can identify the structure of $G/H$ using the First Isomorphism Theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the map $\phi: G \to \mathbb{R}^{\star}$ (where $\mathbb{R}^{\star}$ is the group of real numbers without $0$ under multiplication):
$$ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0& c\end{pmatrix} \mapsto a$$
You can check that this a surjective (since $a \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$) homomorphism with kernel $H$, hence $G/H \cong \mathbb{R}^{\star}$

Comment: I don't know how to decipher  \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0& c\end{pmatrix}.

Comment: @DavidJackson Do you have a problem rendering LaTeX or do you not understand which homomorphism I am referring to?

Comment: I am referring to the map that takes the upper-triangular invertible matrix $(a_{ij})$ to the non-zero real number $a_{11}$.

Comment: I know nothing about LaTeX so I can't identify the homomorphism you are suggesting.  I understand that phi is a map from G to the multiplicative group of reals, but what is its definition?

Comment: That would indeed make H the kernel, yet the codomain of phi would have to be {1} in order for phi to be surjective, meaning that G/H is congruent to {1}.  Is my assessment correct?

Comment: @DavidJackson No, the domain is the group of all upper-triangular matrices, hence the codomain is all non-zero real numbers so the map is surjective. The group H is mapped to 1, so the kernel of the map is H, and by the 1st Isomorphism Theorem, G/H is isomorphic to the non-zero real numbers under multiplication. Is this clear?

Comment: Ah, yes.  Now I see where I erred.  When I constructed phi I had elements of H in mind and so I had phi of A in H being 1 for every A.  Thank you!